# ST_Distance values in kilometers

Tags: postgis

I need to make a query to measure the distance from a given point to all points in a table and return the five closest to that point. The problem is I can't convert the distance to kilometers.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT gid,name , ST_Distance(ST_Transform(g1.geom,2163),ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(37.791458999999996 26.698004299999997)',2100),2163)) as km
    FROM samos As g1   
    WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(g1.geom,2163),ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(37.791458999999996 26.698004299999997)',2100),2163), 50)   
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_Transform(g1.geom,2163),ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(37.791458999999996 26.698004299999997)',2100),2163)) 
    LIMIT 5;
```

The coords is from Greece the table is in 2100 Greece WGS geom(Point,2100) 
Version is 9.3 of postgresql
the out put of cords in table samos
[coordinates](http://postimg.org/image/ceci8c5pz/)

Comment: Please edit the question to include the versions of software (PostgreSQL & PostGIS), the coordinate reference SRID of the "samos" table, and confirm the location by specifying the country.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your SQL statement, so let's take them in order:

1. The `ST_GeomFromText` geometry constructor accepts coordinates in X,Y order, but you've specified them in Latitude,Longitude order, which is Y,X (37.8E 26.7N is in Saudi Arabia)
2. The `ST_GeomFromText` constructor requires SRID of the provided coordinates, which, for WGS1984 decimal degrees, is [4326](http://epsg.io/4326)
3. You've specified your decimal degrees coordinates to fifteen decimal places.  Using a rough conversion factor of 111,120 meters per degree (based on 60 nautical miles), you're asserting precision to 1.11e-10 meters (which is 1.11 angstroms, less than the distance of the carbon-carbon covalent bond).  Even if you lop off nine of those digits, you'll still be within a hand-span of the specified location.
4. When specifying a projection with `ST_Transform` you must be careful to use an appropriate SRID for the geographic area being evaluated.  You've chosen a conic projection over the United States instead of Greece, which will, at best, produce random results.  Instead, use the appropriate SRID, specified elsewhere in the query (`ST_Transform(...,2100)`)
5. The `ST_Distance` function returns values in the projection in which the operation was performed, which for SRID [2100](http://epsg.io/2100) is meters.  Converting to kilometers only requires division by 1000 (`ST_Distance(...) / 1000 as Km`)
6. The `ST_DWithin` function also operates in the projection units, so instead of limiting to 50km, you've limited to 50 meters (`ST_DWithin(...,...,50000)`)

So, putting it all together, you get:

```
SELECT  gid,
        name, 
        ST_Distance(
            g1.geom,
            ST_Transform(
                ST_GeomFromText(
                    'POINT(26.6980043 37.791459)',
                    4326),
                2100)) / 1000.0 as km
FROM    samos g1   
WHERE   ST_DWithin(
            g1.geom,
            ST_Transform(
                ST_GeomFromText(
                    'POINT(26.6980043 37.791459)',
                    4326),
                2100),
            50000)   
ORDER BY ST_Distance(
            g1.geom,
            ST_Transform(
                ST_GeomFromText(
                    'POINT(26.6980043 37.791459)',
                    4326),
                2100))
LIMIT   5;
```

(I didn't build a sample dataset to test this, so it needs validation).

[NOTE: Edited to remove unneeded ST_Transform from g1.geom (2100) to 2100]

Once you get this working, there are plenty of SQL optimizations left, but  that can be a different question (in a different SE group).

Comment: i change the value from 50000 to 5000000 and find me same place in distance give me 4250.2451
50000 is 5 meters ?
and the value i give(5000000) is 500 meters ?
the result wich give me is 4.250 kilometers ?
tis is i dont understand it the all change everything else i understand

Comment: You need to provide the coordinates in your table (as an edit to the question).  If they're not right, then even 50,000km (more than twice the circumference of the Earth) wouldn't matter.

Comment: The `SELECT geom FROM samos LIMIT 5` give Point,2100 
@Vince

Comment: Not used to PostGIS. How about `SELECT ST_AsText(geom) ...` **Place the output in the question!!**

Comment: The query is perfect i have make wrong insert with coords you have wryte , thank you very much thank you

Answer (score 3):

You're using [SRID 2163](http://epsg.io/2163), which is in meters. To convert meters to kilometers, divide by 1000:

> ...ST_Distance(ST_Transform(g1.geom,2163),ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(37.791458999999996 26.698004299999997)',2100),2163))**/1000** ...

Comment: The point in the query is in Saudi Arabia (26.7N 37.8E) or Greece (37.8N, 26.7N), which isn't going to work with a US projection (neither would 26.7N 37.8W or 26.7S 37.8E, or any of the other permutations), so it's probably too early to be doing meter/kilometer conversion.

Comment: To expand a little, 2163 is for a conic projection centered over the US.

Comment: The coords is from Greece the table is in 2100 Greece WGS and the point given in 4326 and make a point in 2100 WGS with 'ST_GeomFromText('POINT(37.791458999999996 26.698004299999997)',2100)' .

Comment: Fly with @Vince -- he's got a mich better answer. Mine's too short-sighted.

Answer (score 2):

I could imagine your coordinates are epsg 4326-coordinates(   37.791458999999996 26.698004299999997 =  Greece, near karlovasi /samos?).if so you should declare them as 4326 (and if all your data has 4326-coordinates, you could use st_distance_spheroid:

```
 SELECT ST_Distance_Spheroid( geom1, geom2),
 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')
```